# Why do some biofuels have a maximal blending ratio?

Tags: organic-chemistry, fuel

[ICAO](https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/GFAAF/Pages/Conversion-processes.aspx) has several conversion processes for sustainable aviation fuel (SAF) with various maximal blending ratios. What would happen if we tried to increase the blending ratio with these processes?

Comment: According to the snapshot taken in July by the WayBack Machine on archive.org ([here](https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/GFAAF/Pages/Conversion-processes.aspx)), ICAO possibly reorganized how to access the content.

Comment: Many pairs of liquids just won't mix in arbitrary ratios.

Comment: Many engines are tuned for specific fuels. Many biofuels have very different characteristics to the fuels engines are tuned for. So too much of them upsets the performance of the engine.

Answer (score 1):

Petrol/gas already is a blend of multiple different hydrocarbons when harvested from soil.

After processing (e.g., washing/drying, passing the [cracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_catalytic_cracking) to split larger molecules into smaller ones, passing the [reformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalytic_reformer) to interconvert some of the molecules into other isomers, and large scale distillations to separate lighter fractions of hydrocarbons (e.g., butane for lighters) from heavier ones, these fractions are *intentionally* mixed again to adjust some desirable properties like the [octane rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating).  To quote:

> «[This] is a standard measure of a fuel's ability to withstand compression in an internal combustion engine without detonating. The higher the octane number, the more compression the fuel can withstand before detonating. Octane rating does not relate directly to the power output or the energy content of the fuel per unit mass or volume, but simply indicates gasoline's capability against compression. »
>
> ([quote from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating))

In this respect, biofuel is nothing particular on its own; again, it is a mixture which, for the purpose of running an engine, has to pass certain criteria.  Some engines are more tolerant about the power fuel used *by design* (e.g., the turbine in [M1 Abrams battle tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1_Abrams#Tactical)), than others.  This is one reason (in states where you gas up your car by yourself) why the nozzles for petrol and diesel differ in diameter.

As aviation *in general* is regulated *internationally* in minute details, the use of [aviation biofuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_biofuel) *as such* as well as *the relative quantity* to conventional fuel however extends beyond what technical is possible (e.g., engine design) without sacrifice of performance/longevity of the engines, but accounts for infrastructure, security, etc.